# Are there any good apps that do financial budgeting by the week instead of by the month?

Tags: finance

All of the applications I have found that are worth using only let you budget by the month. I would like an application that lets you budget by the week as well as do future planning by the week. I get paid weekly and I would like to budget my expenses by the week. I run a tight ship and cannot afford for the over/under days in a pay period across months. For example, I need to budget how much gas, food, and other floating expenses are going to come out of my next check. I'm also trying to pay stuff off early, so I would like to be able to make extra payments any time a paycheck affords that. I would also like to be able to plan out a budget in advance so that I can future plan extra payments by the check, which is weekly and adjust that weekly budget. I also have only $1000 in savings for emergencies. If a kid gets sick or a car breaks down I need to have those funds available. However as soon as the next paychecks start rolling in I need to adjust my budget so that extra funds go back into the emergency fund and then start paying stuff off early again after that is back up to $1000.

reoccurring monthly expenses would be nice, but not a necessity. The minimum requirements would be:

- needs to allow budgeting by the week
- needs to allow for budgeting future weeks
- needs to do future adjustments based on previous budgets (e.g. if there is some left over from the week before, add that to the next week's budget total amount)
- categories for expenses (income optional)

I don't care if it works on windows 7/8 or windows phone. I just want an application. I have an excel spreadsheet that performs all of this with categories. However I have to copy a budget for each week and scroll sideways to get to the current week. I would prefer an application that is focused on budgeting as opposed to a generic solution.

**Apps I've Looked At**

- Mint.com - only monthly budgets(windows phone 8.1)
- Toshl - doesn't seem to like anything except euros (windows phone 8.1)
- Budget Buddy - only monthly budgets (windows phone 8.1)
- Wallet Watch - only has check register style input and graphs to look at the income/expense over time (windows phone 8.1)
- Spending Tracker - Just got this on 10/14/2014, still evaluating, looks promising

Comment: what applications did you try?

Comment: several, I dismissed most of them the moment it did not let me budget by the week. Mint.com is one that I remember.

Comment: Is there a reason why extrapolating doesn't work? e.g. one month = 4x weekly budget

Comment: what do you want to budget? (Your calories intake? Money in your pocket? Your time?) Also please do give some examples of what you have tried. Gratis software or payed (how much)? How do you need this Windwos-Phone-App to interact with you windows 7/8 workstation? Or is that an either/or list?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer - financial budget

Comment: @Raystafarian - because a month doesn't have 4 weeks in it. It has 28-31 days depending on the month. I need to budget stuff weekly as my checks come in.

Comment: @CharlesLambert I currently write a tool for my own finances that has recurring elements. Its still month based but you could include a recurring weekly element for your check. Would that be useful? (But please also answer the other questions from my previous comment)

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer - I updated my question with more information.

Comment: Hi, I looked at Toshl based up the suggestion here - it looks great, really nice UX/UI + functionality (You can turn of the monsters). It's in £ for me (like I need) and it has apps for each of the three phone OSs plus a web app version. Finally, I think weekly periods are fine on it.